# How should I get the corresponding real numpy dtype for a complex dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a more elegant way to get the corresponding real numpy dtype for a possibly complex dtype than the following?

```
import numpy as np

def dtype_to_real(rvs_dtype: np.dtype[Any]) -> np.dtype[Any]:
    return np.empty(0, dtype=rvs_dtype).real.dtype
```

Comment: What is `rvs_dtype`?

Comment: @james the input dtype, which may be a complex dtype.

Comment: Is `rvs_dtype` an actual dtype (an instance of `np.dtype`), or a NumPy type like `np.complex64` (an instance of `type`)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good question.  It's an `np.dtype`.

Comment: 'complex' as in imaginary `1j`, or as in structured array (compound dtype)?  If the default float is `float64` then complex is 2, `complex128`.

Comment: @hpaulj Complex as in sub-dtypes of `np.complexfloating`.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html has a hierarchy tree for dtypes.  `real` is an attribute of numpy array or scalar, but not an attribute of either a function (`np.complex128`) or `dtype`,  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype

Answer (score 3):

As long as the dtypes are not base classes, you should be able to call them with a numeric argument, like `0`.

```
import numpy as np

def dtype_to_real(rvs_dtype: np.dtype[Any]) -> np.dtype[Any]:
    return rvs_dtype.type(0).real.dtype
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement!

Comment: Unfortunately MyPy currently complains that `dtype[Any]` is not callable.  Perhaps this will be added in a future version of NumPy?

Comment: That is a fairly reasonable pull request

Comment: Oh, apparently, I needed `rvs_dtype.type(0).real.dtype`, which works, but the type annotations still don't.  I'm not sure if that will ever be fixed.  Maybe?

Comment: The's a difference between functions that make an array or array scalar, and a dtype.  `np.complex128(0)` makes a complex array scalar.  But `np.complex128(0).dtype` is a `dtype` object, which is not callable.  In `np.array(0, dt)`, `dt` can be `np.complex128` or ''complex128' or `np.dtype('complex128')`, but they are not the same classes.

Comment: I think the original idea is better, since a dtype object is not callable.  And  I doubt if it ever will be.  `numpy` new releases strive for more clarity and consistency.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I know, that's why I commented in the question that it was an `np.dtype` and edited the question with the appropriate annotations.  As for the callability, this solution can just be modified to pull the type out.  I'll edit.